# Getting an unauthorised error when invoking a PageMethod from jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to execute a PageMethod in aspx page using jQuery from a html page, which works fine on my local machine. But when I deploy the web page to a remote production web server, then I get a 401 Unauthorized Error when the ajax request executes. My code is as below.

```
                  $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'SupplierMethods.aspx/GetAgeSummaryForPendingDocuments',
                        data: "{ 'supplierId': '" + vid + "'}",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        timeout: 180000, //3 minutes is timeout for this ajax request
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        beforeSend: function () {

                        },
                        success: function (json) {
                            stats = json.d.StatsBuckets;
                         },
                        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('An error occurred! ' + (errorThrown ? errorThrown : 
                            xhr.satus));
                        }

                    });
                });
```

**UPDATE :**  My problem was due to something very trivial. I copied over the website to remote server, but forgot to copy over the dll's. the PageMethod is compiled into a dll in ASP.Net website, and because it  was missing, so the call to a PageMethod through jQuery ajax came back with an error message. So it seems jQuery API for AJAX are as good as can be.

Comment: Are you passing your function a remote url?

Comment: Farhan- I have got around the loading of remote html page by just using : $("<div></div>").dialog...., and the html page gets hit without issues but an ajax jQuery call in the html causes 401 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this 401 error because the new dll in ASP.Net website that contained the PageMethod I was calling  using jQuery ajax, was not deployed to remote server. **So the moral of the story is - ALWAYS deploy your website with care so you don't miss out on any files.**

***And also make sure your syntax for calling ajax in jQuery adheres to the syntax.***